# Razor behaving different in mobile layout view

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I have following razor in my layout view for mobile:

```
@if (Model.IsWorker)
{
    @:some text
}
else
{
    @:some text
}
```

In this case the Model.IsWorker is false but for some reason the parser desides to skip the else statement and jumps past it.

I have the same logic in my layout for desktop but and that works just fine.

Anyone knows why this is happening?

Comment: is the capital case difference between text in the if and else a typo?

Comment: It is just example text, it is other text in the real solution.

Comment: have you tried inverting the logic, just to check if it is actually executing, or it get some kind of exception or something? 
try
@if (! Model.IsWorker)
{
    @:some text
}
else
{
    @:some text
}

Comment: It interprets the if statement correct also when inverting logic. And then it embarks on the { but then decides to jump past the inside of {}

I've never seen this before.

Comment: Can you break it into 2 separate if statements, (convert else to an inverted if) and tell us the result

Comment: Sorry for wasting your time. The issue had nothing to do with razor it. It seamed like it was skipping the inside of the if but it was the content was hidden with jquery